# Plugin already registered error in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a python project and setup virtual env using virtualenv. Then I activate it with:

```
source bin/activate
```

When I run py.test i got this error and don't know how to fix it:

```
ValueError: Plugin already registered: /my/folder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wheel/test/conftest.pyc=<module 'wheel.test.conftest' from '/my/folder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wheel/test/conftest.pyc'>
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my env?

Comment: Did you set up the virtualenv directly in your project folder? If so, can you try to set it up in a subfolder which pytest doesn't try to collect instead (I usually name it `.venv`)?

Comment: My .bashrc is messed up. Another program auto put python path in front of the $PATH variable so i was always execute python from another program rather then my virtual env